# Highcharts vertical stacked bar chart with negative values, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Is it at all possible to be able to have a vertically stacked bar chart with negative values (using highcharts).

Like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/

```
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, -3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 2, -31, 2, 1]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
```

Unfortunately negative values don't register.

This seems to be a solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-negative-stack/

But for visual reasons I need the bars to be vertical.

Any thoughts on a fix would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: The first fiddle link is dead. Please provide a working link. As a general data visualisation rule, a stacked column/bar chart can only plot positive values.

Comment: The link isn't dead, I think jsfiddle may be down?

Comment: Right. jsfiddle looks down to http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/jsfiddle.net just now. I'll try again later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was trying to achieve the same results. Check this fiddle and let me know =]
I used:

```
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle for vertical stacked bars w negatives](http://jsfiddle.net/wSD7s/)

EDIT: try changing the type to 'bar'. This will make the chart "columns" go horizontal =]

[jsFiddle for horizontal stacked bars w negatives](http://jsfiddle.net/65Tb2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The Highcharts demo code for a 'Stacked column' does not work for negative values for the simple reason that the y-axis range is limited in the example code. The answer lies in removing the `min=0` argument from the `yAxis` options.

The yAxis options should read

```
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    }
```

With these options in place the example code for the 'Stacked Column' chart will display negative values correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stacked column and then set [inverted](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.inverted) parameter as true, then chart will be rotated.

Comment: So when I inverted it, it will be standard stacked column, so to be honest I'm not sure what you would like to achieve. Could you supply a mockup with your concept?

Comment: You managed to get it to rotate? I want to create a chart like this http://oi43.tinypic.com/2mg7g3o.jpg thanks.

Comment: I can't use negative values, unless I am mistaken?

Comment: In case when you cannot use negative values but use negative in data, it is quiate strange.